# Kotlin 1.5.0 does not work with Dagger 2?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a very simple Dagger code as below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var info : Info
    init {
        DaggerMagicBox.create().poke(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}

class Info @Inject constructor() {
    val text = "Hello Dagger 2"
}

@Component
interface MagicBox {
    fun poke(mainClass: MainActivity)
}
```

With plugin as

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

and dependencies as below

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.33'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.33'
```

Where `kotlin_version` is `1.4.32`. It compiles fine.

However when I migrate to `kotlin_version = "1.5.0"`, it just errors out stating

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

without any further detail.

What causes this issue? and how can it be resolved?

Comment: This is the issue in github: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2511

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get more detail by invoking gradle with `--stacktrace`.

This seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2511) that was fixed in dagger 2.34. The newest release is 2.35.1.